# C++ Replace String Character with Character from Specific Index of Vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to replace each instance of a specific character of a string with a specific index character of a vector. Is this possible?

Comment: It's definitely possible.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a reference? I have found plenty on string to string replacements, but not vector to string.

Comment: @motifesta Both contain `char` values, so replacing individual `char` values shouldn't be a problem. It doesn't matter from which container they come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow what you mean, but if I understand correctly, why not?

```
int main() {
    std::string str = "hello";
    std::vector<char> vec;
    vec.push_back('c');
    vec.push_back('b');
    char specific_char = 'l';
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
         if (str[i] == specific_char) {
             str[i] = vec[1];
        }
     }  
     std::cout << str << std::endl; // hebbo
     return 0;
}
```